# How was my postgres docker container hacked / infected

Tags: ubuntu, docker, webserver, postgresql, malware

My VPS have been infected by the [kdevtmpfsi malware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151640/kdevtmpfsi-using-the-entire-cpu), twice. That's the problem, because I've taken every possible precaution after being infected for the first time, and I have no idea how I'm being infected again this time.

Both cases are because of the postgres docker container. After being infected first time,

- I'm using a 20-chars strongest `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to start the official `postgres` docker image,
- and I've removed the port mapping from docker container to the host.

The postgres can only be accessed by another docker container (not even by the host), using a docker network I created myself. Such docker container was started from `cosmtrek/air`, a Go based live building environment, and my Go web application is super simple, which doesn't even serve the `/` root.

The Go `air` docker container is the only one having its port mapping from docker container to the host, thus expose to the world.

Yet, the postgres docker container was infected again, under the condition that I deemed impossible.

Any hints please. thx.

PS. I'm going to start the official `postgres` docker image again as before, but no Go web this time, to prove the infection has nothing to do with my Go app. Let's see...

Comment: What image are you pulling? Maybe the image is already infected?

Comment: _"the official postgres docker image"_, as put in the OP -- postgres       latest    69e765e8cdbe   13 days ago   412MB

Comment: maybe this is more suitable for your question ... https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, but I don't have an account over there, and opening an account over there just for this single question seems to me not worth the trouble. Moreover, if you take a look at the referenced infection case, it is not even a programming question but got answers on stackoverflow. I.e., if people know the answer then they'd reply, no matter where it is; if not, posting to security.stackexchange.com might not get answers either.